# Unity not starting for old user account

Tags: unity

Installed 11.10 fresh but with a previously used /home/bob directory mounted.

unity does not start when i log in as 'bob',  but does work as a guest, as well as for a new users account i made, 'bob2'.

if i start in 2d then run unity from command line, it works (this is my current work-around).

things i have tried:

- `unity --reset`
- removed all settings directories (rm -rf .gconf .gnome2 etc)
- installed ccsm and un/re-enabled unity, and removed conflicts (there were some)

none seem to solve the problem. any ideas?

Comment: Did you try removing the `~/home/bob/.compiz-1` folder?

Answer (score 2):

Removing `.Xauthority` and `~/.config/autostart` fixed the problem.

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
rm -rf ~/.config/autostart
```